# Reset Droppable Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable, jquery-ui-selectable

I have a simple script that acts as a filemanager. The idea is to select a group of files/directories and drop them into another directory. However, if a directory is .ui-selected then it should not be droppable. The current script I have so far works as expected if I only select a group of files/directories once, but if I unselect and reselect a different group it no longer works.

Here is a fiddle that demonstrates the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/3gggh6bg/19/

Here is the js:

```
$(function() {
  $("#filemanager").selectable({
    filter: 'tr',
    start: function() {
      $("tr.ui-selected").each(function() {
        $(this).draggable('destroy');
      });
    },
    stop: function() {
      $("tr.ui-selected").draggable({
        helper: function() {
          var dom = [];

          dom.push("<div style=\"border:2px solid black;width:50px;height:20px;line-height:25px;\">",
            "<center>Files Selected: 1</center></div>");

          return $(dom.join(''));
        },

        revert: 'invalid',
        appendTo: 'parent',
        containment: '#filemanager',
        axis: 'y',
        cursor: '-moz-grabbing'
      });

      $(".droppable").not('.ui-selected').droppable({
        //accept: ".ui-selected",
        //activeClass: "ui-state-hover",
        hoverClass: "ui-state-active",
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Any help appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I have looked over your fiddle and still am not sure what is not working. When I select a row and drag it, I can drop it on another row. I can then repeat this with other rows.

Comment: If you select the top 3 droppables and drag the top selected droppable onto the bottom 2 droppables that are selected they will not work (as expected). However, if you attempt to do this again on the bottom 3 without refreshing the page it will still hold the top 3 as selected and not the bottom 3. The ui-selected does not seem to reset. I hope this makes sense, if you need me to I can great a gif that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Still not able to replicate the issue and it's still not clear what you're trying to accomplish. Selectable appears to be working properly.

Comment: If a droppable row has the class ui-selected then droppable should no longer work. This only works once, and if you reselect a different group of droppables ui-selected seems to stick to the last group that was selected. http://imgur.com/SCNGFdK shows the issue. It works on the first selected group, but after that it no longer works as expected (if droppable has ui-selected, no longer be droppable).

Comment: Ok, so when I select a number of rows, there is no function that removes `droppable` from the lists of classes for those items that are now `ui-selected`. I see the following classes on the rows I selected: `selectable droppable ui-selectee ui-selected ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle` I guess I am trying to understand what you expected to have happen.

Comment: Also, my fiddle does not respond the way that you showed in your GIF. I cannot drop the selected rows into any of the rows except the top 2. But I can on the second pass, I just got it to do what you described! Ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an event that we were overlooking. I suspect I was investigating this using the same logic you were. That when the `stop` event was triggered, I should be able to find the unselected items or the selected items, and make some droppable while others would be left untouched.

This is the case initially, but the event we were failing to look at was the `unselected` event. This is triggered when the sate of an item is changed back from selected to unselected. Here is what I ended up with:

https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/3gggh6bg/21/

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
  $("#filemanager").selectable({
    filter: 'tr',
    start: function() {
      $("tr.ui-selected").each(function() {
        $(this).draggable('destroy');
      });
    },
    selected: function(e, ui) {
      console.log(e.target, " Selected triggered.");
      $(ui.selected).removeClass("droppable");
    },
    stop: function() {
      console.log("Stop triggered.");
      $("tr.ui-droppable").droppable("destroy");
      $("tr.ui-selected").draggable({
        helper: function() {
          var c = $("tr.ui-selected").length;
          var $h = $("<div>", {
            class: "ui-helper"
          }).css({
            display: "block",
            border: "2px solid black",
            width: "50px",
            height: "20px",
            "line-height": "25px"
          }).html("<center>Files Selected: " + c + "</center>");
          return $h;
        },
        revert: 'invalid',
        appendTo: 'parent',
        containment: '#filemanager',
        axis: 'y',
        cursor: '-moz-grabbing'
      });
      $("tr.droppable").droppable({
        hoverClass: "ui-state-active"
      });
    },
    unselected: function(e, ui) {
      console.log(e.target, "Unselect triggered.");
      $(ui.unselected).addClass("droppable");
      $("tr.droppable").droppable({
        hoverClass: "ui-state-active"
      });
    }
  });
});
```

This resets the `droppable` status from the selected items each time items are selected. If this is not working the way you expect, please comment and provide more info.

Comment: This worked great! Thank you! I apologize that I didn't get back to your comment fast enough above, as well as not explaining the issue better. For any future user that want to use this out of the box, I added `$(ui.unselected).not('.file').addClass("droppable");` and added the class file to non droppable elements, so when unselected is called it adds droppable back to the correct elements. Also, I tried `.droppable("destroy");` in the start function before and it completely broke selectable from being restarted, I am not sure why it worked for your example. I didn't try the unselected fctn.

Comment: It's due to elements not being assigned droppable when trying to run destroy option.